# Are there Ethereum API wrappers?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, golang

I'm looking into developing some Go software on Ethereum and I'm wondering - are there any API wrappers around for Ethereum (something like [BTCSuite's BTCRPCClient](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcrpcclient) is for Bitcoin)? I know there is [a whole Go Ethereum implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum), but I'm looking for more lightweight way of interacting just with the JSON RPC server, rather than interacting with the whole network directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet.

We've just revamped the server side RPC internals in develop and are still ironing out some quirks. I can imagine we would soon-ish start working towards the directions of providing some Go client APIs, but we're not there yet. If you just need a few specific ones, they are relatively easy to implement (here's a few we needed for a hackathon last week https://github.com/gophergala2016/etherapis/blob/master/etherapis/geth/api.go).